# encountering black screen when running veins-launchd for connecting veins to sumo-gui

Tags: omnet++, veins, sumo

I'm trying to use OMNeT++ version omnetpp-6.0pre15  and sumo 1.11.0 and connecting veins to sumo. My system is MacOS Monetrey.When I run the following:

```
downloads/veins-master/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c ~/sumo/bin/sumo-gui
```

it shows a black page while time increases and the stops. My sumo-gui and netedit runs correctly and they both show the simulation. But the black screen rises when I use vein to run sumo-gui, I mean omnetpp.ini file in veins from OMNeT++. Also when I run:

```
downloads/veins-master/sumo-launchd.py -vv -c ~/sumo/bin/sumo-gui
```

it shows me the following

> Listening on port 9999.

I tried the following command:

```
cd downloads
cd veins-master
cd bin
python veins_launchd -vv -c ~/sumo/bin/sumo-gui
```

the above also shows a black screen for sumo-gui after running veins> omnetpp.ini

This is the veins-master I downloaded:

> https://github.com/sommer/veins/tree/master/

I appreciate if anyone can suggest me how can I fix it.

Comment: Does the issue also occur when you start the `sumo-gui` without Veins?

Comment: No it doesn't occur without veins.

Comment: Did you try the solutions mentioned here https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/8208 and here https://github.com/eclipse/sumo/issues/7830 ?